# What is the difference between wibox and wibox widget?

Tags: awesome-wm

I was wondering what I should use when I am declaring a new widget. Because to me

```lua
local some_widget = wibox({})
```

and

```lua
local some_widget = wibox.widget {}
```

is the same

Answer (score 1):

Wibox (widget box) is a special type of window where you put custom widgets.

The widgets are the things you put in a wibox.

The wibox is (mostly) the base class for other type of bar/popups/titlebars/tooltip/menus across AwesomeWM. You rarely create them directly. Widgets, on the other hand, is something that is more commonly used.